# Data access at socket at OS level TCP/IP UDP

Tags: c++, networking, tcp, udp, winsock

I am no expert in network programming although I do have some knowledge of Winsock, for any experts out there I am wanting to know if there is a way I can capture data at the socket coming from an application on my machine and do something with it. ie: I sent a message via MSN but I want to capture it from a custom application before it actually gets sent.

Thanks.

Comment: And on what level do you want it? TCP/UDP payload, TCP/UDP packets, IP packets, even below?

Comment: Thanks for the reply devianfan, I would like to add extra custom security on outgoing data so I believe it would be TCP/UDP payload.....

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly *capture* the packets.  Tools like Wireshark are proof of that (have a look at the [WinPCap](http://www.winpcap.org) library).  Just keep in mind that you are capturing what an application sends, so if the application sends encrypted data using SSL/TLS or similar, that is what you are going to get.  You won't be able to decrypt and view the original data without the security keys used.

*Altering* and/or *discarding* packets, on the other hand, is much harder, requiring much lower level access to the system, but it is possible (see [WinDivert](http://reqrypt.org/windivert.html), for example).

Comment: Hi Remy, thanks for the reply, I do not want to alter the contents however I would like to add extra encryption to the outgoing packet to ensure that data cannot be decrypted and examined if it happens to be retained along its route. Cheers.

Comment: Encrypt the content == altering. And if you encrypt your MSN message successfully, how should the receiver of your packet understand it?